# How to Solve 'Context' is a type,which is not valid in the given context?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Android and xamarin 
I want to add listview in my tab that built with fragment.

My code is here, it is a sample code for xamarin to build three tab that I want to build a listview in SpeakerFragment:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace com.xamarin.example.actionbar.tabs
{
    public class SpeakersFragment :Fragment
    {

        private List<string> mItems;
        private ListView mListView;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listviewlayout,container,false);
            mListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myList);

            mItems = new List<string>();
            mItems.Add("One");
            mItems.Add("Two");
            mItems.Add("Three");
            mItems.Add("Four");
            mItems.Add("Five");

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, objects: mItems.ToArray());

            mListView.Adapter = adapter;
            return view;
        }

    }

    public class SessionsFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.simple_fragment, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).SetText(Resource.String.sessions_tab_label);
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_sessions);
            return view;
        }
    }

    public class WhatsOnFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.simple_fragment, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).SetText(Resource.String.whatson_tab_label);
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_whats_on);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this error occur?

> 'Context' is a type,which is not valid in the given context?

Comment: You need an instance of `Context`, not the type. I suppose you need something like `new ArrayAdapter<string>(myContext, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, objects: mItems.ToArray())` where `myContext` is an instance of `Context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `Fragment.Context` is only available since API level 23. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()

You can use `Activity` or `Application.Context` instead. Or set the compile version to API level 23, but then you might end up with some crashes on older Android versions, if you don't set the minimum suppored version to 23, too.

```
ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, objects: mItems.ToArray())
```